# Updating iOS app scaling issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm trying to update an old iOS app (iPhoneOS 3) and for the most part it has gone smoothly. One problem I can't figure out, however, is related to the display of my views. They seem to have margins on either side (regardless of device) and in one case (a UIImageView) the image is not scaled to fit the screen. In the following screenshot the UIImageView has margins on either side and the right side of the image is clipped.

[image: The image in this UIImageView has margins on either side and is clipped on the right.]

In the Interface Builder the UIImageView looks like the following (I have constraints set on all sides that should make the view take up the whole display).

[image: UIImageView in Interface Builder]

I have an OpenGL view that also renders with margins:

[image]

I know this is a bit vague, but I wasn't sure what details would be helpful. As far as I can tell I don't have any margins set anywhere. Does anyone have any idea about what could be causing the problem?